# Android Studio, Gradle DSL method not found: 'compilecmdip()'

Tags: android

[image]

I bought a new computer. I want copy my android codes to my new computer. First, I commit my code by svn on my old computer, and then I check out the codes on my new computer.

My old computer android studio version is 2.3.3 and my new computer android studio version is 4.0.1. Open the project by android studio 4.0.1, I got the error like this picture, I don't know why.

Comment: compile is obsolete and replaced with implementation keyword

Comment: click on upgrade plugin  and try again

Comment: what is compilecmdip ?

Comment: click on upgrade ,show a confirm dialog"failed to update the version of the android gradle plugin please click "ok" to perform a textual search and then update the build files manually "